# WordPress TinyMCE button, will not open window

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I try to make a plugin for wordpress, where I need a button in the TinyMCE editor. I have tried several tutorials, and I can get the button in the toolbar, but it will not open a window. I have tried to follow this example: http://return-true.com/2011/12/adding-tinymce-button-to-wordpress-via-a-plugin/

My javascript code:

```
// JavaScript Document
(function() {
    tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.afflpad", {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addCommand("afflpad_click", function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    file : url.substring(0, url.length -2) + "afflpad_selector.php",
                    width : 480,
                    height : auto,
                    inline: 1,
                }, {
                    plugin_url : url    
                });
            });
            ed.addButton("afflpad_button", {
                title : "Affiliate Link",
                cmd : "afflpad_click",
                image : url.substring(0, url.length -2) + 'img/afflpad_button.png'
            });
        },
        getInfo : function() {
            return {
                longname : "Affiliate links",
                author : "NAME",
                authorurl : "HOMEPAGE",
                infourl : "HOMEPAGE",
                version : tinymce.majorVersion + "." + tinymce.minorVersion
            };
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add("afflpad", tinymce.plugins.afflpad);
})();
```

And my PHP code for implementing in wordpress:

```
function afflpad_mce_buttonhooks() {
    if(current_user_can("edit_posts") && current_user_can("edit_pages") && get_user_option("rich_editing") == "true") {
        add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "afflpad_register_tinymce_javascript");
        add_filter("mce_buttons", "afflpad_register_mce_buttons");  
    }
}

add_action("init", "afflpad_mce_buttonhooks");

function afflpad_register_tinymce_javascript($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array["afflpad"] = plugins_url("/js/afflpad_tinymce_plugin.js", __file__);
    return $plugin_array;
}

function afflpad_register_mce_buttons($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "|", "afflpad_button");
    return $buttons;
}
```

Can someone see why I can't open a window, when clicking on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! It works now.

The problem is that auto should be "auto". But I can't get auto to work as well, so now I have just a fixed height.

```
height : "auto",
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies, but I've seen issues due to a conflict between PHP short open tags `<?` and the use of those characters in the tinymce jQuery library.

Ended up modding wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js (or possibly wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.js)

Changed incidents of

```
{c.push("<?",
```

to

```
{c.push("<" + "?",
```

Thanks the MarcBB for the fix.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I will not fix it by changing wp-files. Because then everyone who use the plugin, has to do the same? And other plugins with buttons works fine.

Comment: It was a shot in the dark - tinymce stopped rendering properly for us after an update and it turned out that it was the enabled short-tags in the server's PHP settings that caused our problems.In our case, the choices were between disabling short tags, or altering tinymce.